# Clicking a panel will trigger the containing label's click event

Tags: vb.net, events

I made a custom calendar and and I'm having a bit of trouble. As the title suggests, I want to trigger click event when I click its panel. Here's my code.

Click Event:

```
Private Sub label_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles m1.Click, m2.Click, m3.Click, m4.Click, m5.Click, m6.Click, tu1.Click, tu2.Click, tu3.Click, tu4.Click, tu5.Click, tu6.Click, w1.Click, w2.Click, w3.Click, w4.Click, w5.Click, w6.Click, th1.Click, th2.Click, th3.Click, th4.Click, th5.Click, th6.Click, f1.Click, f2.Click, f3.Click, f4.Click, f5.Click, f6.Click, sa1.Click, sa2.Click, sa3.Click, sa4.Click, sa5.Click, sa6.Click, su1.Click, su2.Click, su3.Click, su4.Click, su5.Click, su6.Click

    Dim clickedLabel = TryCast(sender, Label)
    If clickedLabel IsNot Nothing Then
        If clickedLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black Then Exit Sub
        clickedLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
       End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. You may need to tweak the code to find the label.

```
Private Sub panel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim panel = CType(sender, Panel)
    Dim label = panel.Controls.OfType(Of Label).Single
    label_Click(label, e)
End Sub
```

Here's an example of dynamically attaching the handlers. Once again you'll need to tweak the code to find the panels / labels but it'll save you having to add all the handles clauses.

```
Private Sub AddHandlers()
    For Each panel In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
        Dim label = panel.Controls.OfType(Of Label).Single
        AddHandler panel.Click, AddressOf panel_Click
        AddHandler label.Click, AddressOf label_click
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I still can't figure out how to use the AddHandlers Sub though. If it's alright with you, could you explain it to me further? I could post the other parts of my code.

Comment: I do it like that because I'm lazy and too prone to error. `AddHandler object.EventName, Handler` will cause `Handler` to run any time `object` raises `EventName`. In that regard its similar to the Handles / withevents pattern (in fact all handles / withevents is doing is managing that behind the scenes). So you want to call this on every panel object in your form, hence why I loop over the controls collection. If your panels are children of another layout (eg TableLayout) then iterator over that instead. Eg `Me.TableLayout1.Controls.OfType(of Panel)()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your code.

`label1_Click(sender, e)`